# vba apply style

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I have this piece of code that inserts an excel cell value into a word document:

```
    Set wrdRange = wrdDoc.Range
    With wrdRange
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
         .InsertParagraphAfter
         xText = Rng.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
         .InsertAfter xText
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End With
```

I need to style **xText** with H1, but don't get it.
xText may contain many word.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Set wrdRange = wrdDoc.Range
With wrdRange
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    xText = Rng.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
    .InsertAfter xText

    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(xText), Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")

    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
End With
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but if fails with a runtime error (Selection is not supporter). After some research I found the way to do it:   With wrdRange
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd  
             .InsertParagraphAfter
             xText = Rng.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
             .InsertAfter xText
             .Paragraphs(2).Style = "Heading 1"
             .InsertParagraphAfter
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End With